# while copying files using File.copy i get error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

when i run file.copy to copy files in network path for large files i get the below error but in back end files are getting copied twice.

> This site can’t be reached  The webpage at http://******************* might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address. ERR_INVALID_HANDLE

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in grdAppDetails.Rows)
{
    Label lblPublishPath = (Label)row.FindControl("lblPublishPath");
    Label lblBackupPath = (Label)row.FindControl("lblBackupPath");
    string BackupPath = lblBackupPath.Text + "\\" + drpApplication.SelectedValue.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
    DirectoryCopy(lblPublishPath.Text, BackupPath, true);
    DirectoryCopy(txtFolderUpload.Text, lblPublishPath.Text, true);
    deploymentdata.AddAppLogDetails(drpApplication.SelectedValue.ToString(), drpEnv.SelectedValue.ToString(), lblUserName.Text, DateTime.Now, txtFolderUpload.Text, BackupPath, lblPublishPath.Text, txtComments.Text, filenames);
}
```

Comment: when i debug and run i don't get error but when i run it directly or when i host and run then i get this error. thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the id that the app pool runs under have authority to the directories?

Comment: yes, i can copy small files with out any issues

Comment: prob is not becoz of file.copy but it is become load is slow. so what can i go so that website waits till it loads

Answer (score 0):

try to :

1- ping the destination to be sure that you have access.

2- once the ping succeed , try to check if  you can write file from your machine

you can do it like this : Properties-->share --> and add your user if you don't have access to the directory